# more than one abstract in amsart document

Tags: abstract, amsart

As far as I know,  we can write only  one abstract in an *amsart* document.
Is it possible to write several abstracts  with the amsart template?

Comment: you can't without redefine the abstract environment

Answer (score 6):

If you are happy with the first abstract being in the document's main language, you can define a `\newabstract` command taking as argument the language you want to typeset the second (third, …) abstract in.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{amsart}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian,english]{babel}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\newabstract}[1]{%
  \par\bigskip
  \csname otherlanguage*\endcsname{#1}%
  \csname captions#1\endcsname
  \item[\hskip\labelsep\scshape\abstractname.]
}

\begin{document}

\title{A title}
\author{A. Uthor}

\begin{abstract}
This is the abstract in the main language. \lipsum[2]

\newabstract{italian}
E questo è il sunto in un'altra lingua. \lipsum[3]
\end{abstract}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

I use `\otherlanguage*` and `\captions{...}` in order to avoid a command such as `\selectlanguage` writes unwanted notes in the `.aux` file.

[image]

A version that allows for the abstracts to be given in any order, with a redefinition of the environment accepting the language as an optional argument (default the language which is current when `\begin{abstract} is issued, usually the main document's language).

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{amsart}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian,english]{babel}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{abstract}[1][\languagename]{%
  \ifx\maketitle\relax
    \ClassWarning{\@classname}{Abstract should precede
      \protect\maketitle\space in AMS document classes; reported}%
  \fi
  \global\setbox\abstractbox=\vtop \bgroup
    \unvbox\abstractbox % add the previous abstracts
    \medskip
    \normalfont\Small
    \list{}{\labelwidth\z@
      \leftmargin3pc \rightmargin\leftmargin
      \listparindent\normalparindent \itemindent\z@
      \parsep\z@ \@plus\p@
      \let\fullwidthdisplay\relax
    }%
    % change the current language
    \csname otherlanguage*\endcsname{#1}\csname captions#1\endcsname
    \item[\hskip\labelsep\scshape\abstractname.]%
}{%
  \endlist\egroup
  \ifx\@setabstract\relax \@setabstracta \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\title{A title}
\author{A. Uthor}

\begin{abstract}[italian]
E questo è il sunto in un'altra lingua. \lipsum[3]
\end{abstract}

\begin{abstract}
This is the abstract in the main language. \lipsum[2]
\end{abstract}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

[image]