# Add one more abstract in document class amsbook

Tags: abstract, amsbook

I am trying to add one more abstract in document class amsbook. To this end, I find a good and simple solution [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228115/more-than-one-abstract-in-amsart-document). However it doesn't fit my situation because the abstracts in my book is a bit too long. I would like to know how I can fix it, like start the second abstract in the next page.

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt, final]{amsbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[german,english]{babel}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\newabstract}[1]{%
  \par\bigskip
  \csname otherlanguage*\endcsname{#1}%
  \csname captions#1\endcsname
  \item[\hskip\labelsep\scshape\abstractname.]
}

\begin{document}

\title{T}
\author{A}

\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[2]
\lipsum[2]
\lipsum[2]

\newabstract{german}
\lipsum[3]
\lipsum[3]
\lipsum[3]
\end{abstract}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

It appears like:

[image: MWE]

Comment: The abstract in `amsbook` is typeset as a box, which means page breaks are not possible. You could try to print the additional abstract after the `\maketitle`, i.e., as normal text (with page breaks) but with an abstract-like appearance with extra margins and a run-in smallcaps title.

Comment: I can't test, hence a comment.  This is how I'd do it.  Set both abstracts in the same box, English abstract first.  At the end of that, skip a line, `\smallskip \begingroup` set the language, `\noindent \textsc{Zusammenfassung.}` and continue with the German abstract.  At the end, finish with `\par \endgroup`.  Of course, with an abstract this big, it may not fit on a page, so the box is a bad idea.  Send a complaint to tech-support@ams.org .